# Im trying to parse text from xml file using XDocument but not all the results are as i wanted to be why?

Tags: c#

I have a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string fileName = @"d:\adilipman1937067724.xml";
            ParseAndDisplayXml(fileName);
        }
```

And the function:

```
private void ParseAndDisplayXml(string filename)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);
            var list = document.Root.Elements("Message")
                .Select(
                e => new
                {
                    Date = e.Attribute("Date").ToString(),
                    Time = e.Attribute("Time").ToString(),
                    Text = e.Attribute("Text").ToString()
                }
                );
 string result="";
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
               result += string.Format("Date--{0},Time--{1},Text--{2}", item.Date, item.Time, item.Text);


            }
textBox1.Text = result;
        }
```

The result of Date and Time are ok but the result of Text is wrong.
This is the result of the Text: 
     hello
And what i need to get in Text is only hello
The results of Date and Time are: Date="31/01/2012" and Time="10:15:42"

The problem is getting the Text.

Then what im getting in the textBox1 when im running the program is a mess:

Date--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:15:42",Text--הייDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:15:55",Text--הייתה לי בעיה עם התוכנת ברקים אבל עכשיו הכל עובד.Date--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:15:58",Text--מה השלב הבא ?Date--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:16:27",Text--אמרת לי בזמנו לחשב ממוצע של 1000 ערכים ? הכוונה 1000 ערכים בפריים ? כי בפריים יש 256 מספרים לא ?Date--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:17:03",Text--לחשב ממוצע של 1000 הערכים הגבוהים ביותר בהיסטוגרמהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:17:10",Text--ז"א בפרייםDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:17:14",Text--לא בהיסטוגרמהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:17:20",Text--בעזרת ההיסטוגרמהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:17:50",Text--תחשוב למשל איך אתה מחשב ממוצע של כל הערכים בפריים בעזרת היסטוגרמהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:18:08",Text--אחרי תחשוב איך אתה מוצא את המספר הגבוה ביותר בעזרת היסטוגרמהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:18:29",Text--ואחרי זה תחשוב נגיד איך אתה מחשב ממוצע של 10 הערכים הגבוהים בפריים בעזרתהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:18:38",Text--תנסה לחשוב על זהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:18:45",Text--ואז תכתוב פונקציהDate--Date="31/01/2012",Time--Time="10:18:54",Text--

And the original xml file content for example is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='MessageLog.xsl'?>
<Log FirstSessionID="1" LastSessionID="2">
  <Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:15:42" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:15:42.467Z" SessionID="1">
    <From>
      <User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/>
    </From>
    <To>
      <User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/>
    </To>
    <Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">היי</Text>
  </Message>
  <Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:15:55" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:15:55.097Z" SessionID="1">
    <From>
      <User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/>
    </From>
    <To>
      <User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/>
    </To>
    <Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">הייתה לי בעיה עם התוכנת ברקים אבל עכשיו הכל עובד.</Text>
  </Message>
  <Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:15:58" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:15:58.897Z" SessionID="1">
    <From>
      <User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/>
    </From>
    <To>
      <User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/>
    </To>
    <Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">מה השלב הבא ?</Text>
  </Message>
  <Message Date="31/01/2012" Time="10:16:27" DateTime="2012-01-31T08:16:27.775Z" SessionID="1">
    <From>
      <User FriendlyName="Chocolade"/>
    </From>
    <To>
      <User FriendlyName="adilipman@yahoo.com"/>
    </To>
    <Text Style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#000000; ">אמרת לי בזמנו לחשב ממוצע של 1000 ערכים ? הכוונה 1000 ערכים בפריים ? כי בפריים יש 256 מספרים לא ?</Text>
  </Message>
</Log>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in XML file you provided, `Text` is not an *attribute*, but *child tag* of `Message`.

What you need to do is select children node you want (for example using `node.SelectNodes` or `node.SelectSingleNode`) and then get it's text value (`node.InnerText`).

As for *mess* in the textBox1, you need to add `\r\n` after each line (`string.Format("...\r\n", ...`)

---

Okay, let's take a look at your XML file: and you should do some reading if necessary, to have the basic understanding of `attributes` and `elements` that XML file consists of.

So your file: has element `Message`, which has `attributes`: *Date*, *Time*, *DateTime* and *SessionID*. Next, this `Message` element has *child nodes*: `From`, `To` and `Text`, two first of which have no attributes, while third one has *Style* attribute, and inner text (everything between `<Text>` and `</Text>` tags.

Here's how to use `XmlNode` class:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument()
xml.Load("path_to_xml_file");
```

Here we loaded whole xml file to an object. Now we can select specific node(s):

```
XmlNodeList messages = xml.SelectNodes("/root/Message");
```

`"/root/Message"` part is a `XPath`, you might want to read about that, it's pretty useful...

Now, all `Message` nodes in our file are in a list `messages`. We can iterate it:

```
foreach (XmlNode message in messages)
  { ... }
```

and for each node we can grab its attributes:

```
#msg is a XmlNode from messages list
#XmlNode.Attributes is a list of all attributes in given node
XmlNode dateAttribute = msg.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Date");
```

Notice how our attribute is a XmlNode itself. If there was no such attribute in the node, then `dateAttribute == null`, otherwise, its value is accessible via `dateAttribute.Value`.
I usually make auxiliary function for this:

```
public static string GetStringAttribute(XmlNode node, string name, string defaultValue="")
    {
        XmlNode attrNode = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem(name);
        if (attrNode == null)
            return defaultValue;
        else
            return attrNode.Value.Trim();
    }
```

Also from our `Message` node, we can extract its `Text` part:

```
XmlNode textNode = msg.SelectSingleNode("Text");
string textBetweenTags = textNode.InnerText;
```

I hope this clarifies things a little bit, to get understanding of how XML files are built, what's `XPath` and how to use it I recommend [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/).

I won't correct all of your code, but using it and remembering to put `\r\n` after adding each line, you should get output you want, good luck!

Comment: wasly could you show me please exmaple how to use the node.SelectNodes with my code ? Thanks.

Comment: I may have went too quickly with that, as you use XElement class. Therefore i think `e.Element("Text").ToString()` will be sufficient. I myself to parse XML files use `XMLNode` class and `SelectNodes` or `SelectSingleNode` to get elements - these functions use `xpath` to find desired element inside node you're working on...

Comment: Wasly no the e.Element did not do the work. Then show me how to use the XMLNode ? Thanks.

Comment: I did extend my answer, I hope this helps.